# Custom Error using Global.asax asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I made an error; the page directs users in case of error in any applications within the website. I made `Global.asax` rather than using Webconfig. My question is : Is it possible to redirect user from `Global.asax` for those statusCodes "401", "404" and "500" in case of error rather than using Webconfig ?

In other words, using `Global.aspx` rather than Webconfig !? I am just curious to know.

Thank you

Comment: It is possible, however I really don't see any value added...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14822435/response-redirect-not-working-in-global-asax

Comment: using web.config is better just search on google for <customErrors>  in web.config

Comment: check my answer and tell me if helped you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    protected void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         Exception ex = this.Server.GetLastError();

         if(ex is HttpException)
         {
              HttpException httpEx = (HttpException)ex;

              if(httpEx.GetHttpCode() == 401)
              {
                   Response.Redirect("YourPage.aspx");
              }
         }
    }
```

Yes it is possible. Here is little code example. This should be added in `Global.asax.cs`.

Comment: Do you need to clear the error from the server? and GetHttpCode gives me an error ?

Comment: No you don't need to clear anything. GetHttpCode gives you the code of the error, it can be 401,404,403 and so on.

Comment: Thank you for your replies, but noticed there is a typo error in one of your codes in if(httpEx.GetHhttpCode() == 401)

Answer (score 2):

Never set `customErrors` to `Off` in your Web.config file if you do not have an `Application_Error` handler in your `Global.asax` file. Potentially compromising information about your Web site can be exposed to anyone who can cause an error to occur on your site.

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs

  // Get the exception object.
  Exception exc = Server.GetLastError();

  // Handle HTTP errors
  if (exc.GetType() == typeof(HttpException))
  {
    // The Complete Error Handling Example generates
    // some errors using URLs with "NoCatch" in them;
    // ignore these here to simulate what would happen
    // if a global.asax handler were not implemented.
      if (exc.Message.Contains("NoCatch") || exc.Message.Contains("maxUrlLength"))
      return;

    //Redirect HTTP errors to HttpError page
    Server.Transfer("HttpErrorPage.aspx");
  }

  // For other kinds of errors give the user some information
  // but stay on the default page
  Response.Write("<h2>Global Page Error</h2>\n");
  Response.Write(
      "<p>" + exc.Message + "</p>\n");
  Response.Write("Return to the <a href='Default.aspx'>" +
      "Default Page</a>\n");

  // Log the exception and notify system operators
  ExceptionUtility.LogException(exc, "DefaultPage");
  ExceptionUtility.NotifySystemOps(exc);

  // Clear the error from the server
  Server.ClearError();
}
```

Also once can get error code like

```
exc.GetHttpCode() == 403 so that 

if (exc!= null && httpEx.GetHttpCode() == 403)
    {
        Response.Redirect("/youraccount/error/forbidden", true);
    }
    else if (exc!= null && httpEx.GetHttpCode() == 404)
    {
        Response.Redirect("/youraccount/error/notfound", true);
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("/youraccount/error/application", true);
    }
```

Also see [`Custom error in global.asax`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25321794/custom-error-in-global-asax)